# How does TensorFlow calculate the gradients of an FFT layer?

Tags: tensorflow

If I insert the function, e.g., `tf.fft(input, name=None)`, into a neural network, how does TensorFlow calculate the gradients in backpropagation?

I didn't find any documentation about this.

I am using TensorFlow 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just inserting the tf.fft(...) function in the middle of a model I'm not certain tensorflow will even be able to handle a forward pass. If you read the docs on tf.signal.fft (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/signal/fft) or even just read the tf.fft function header, they both require inputs with dtype=tf.complex64 or dtype=tf.complex128. Perhaps tensorflow will cast float32 inputs to complex and then back again, allowing you to complete a forward pass, I'm not sure, but from what I can gather from reading tensorflow gradient documents casting values causes a disconnect between error gradient and Model parameters, meaning a backward pass won't work. You could try implementing a custom fft function which doesn't cast values and see if that works? It's not so easy though.